# How to integrate a new file in a module in SugarCRM 7?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I added a new button in `detailviews` of a module, having the attribute `onClick="genReg(name, type)"`.

I created this function in a *.js* file. This function (`genReg(name, type)`)  send the variables to a PHP file, *generateReg.php*, using JSON.

The file is in *module_name* folder. In this PHP file I try to create a new object of modules Reglement (it's a custom module) and add new item to the database.

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the path to the module Reglement.

I included it as follows:

```
require_once('modules/Reglement/Reglement.php');
```

but got the following error:

> Error:  Failed opening required 'modules/Reglement/Reglement.php'

Paths to my files:

> > js:  custom/module_name/js/generate.js
> >     php:  custom/module_name/generateReg.php

Which file shall I include in order to recognize all the path?

Comment: Are you calling to and loading `custom/module_name/generateReg.php` directly? If so it will not load paths correctly, you'll need to use a valid entry point to the system.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I did that error :D, calling directly. I change the url in js file like this http://localhost.net/index.php?entryPoint=generateReg and it works now. Thank a lot.

But I've got an other error. When I call this url I send POST data. In my file I have the POST data, but the function json_decode($_POST['data']) return nothing.
print_r($_POST['data']) -> return a valid json 
json_decode($_POST['data']) return nothing

Do you know if Sugar do something that change the behaviour of json_decode?